# Prototype select all checkboxes code works in IE, but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, prototypejs

I'm using prototype 1.6.0.1.  I'm trying to select all the checkboxes when clicking a button.  This code works in IE 6, but does NOT in Firefox 3.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<input class="submit" type="button" value="check all" onclick="$(this.form).getInputs('checkbox').each(function (elem) {elem.checked = true;});" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I created a very basic page to test your issue:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="prototype-1.6.0.3.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" id="test1" /> Test 1<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" id="test2" /> Test 2<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" id="test3" /> Test 3<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" id="test4" /> Test 4<br/>
        <input class="submit" type="button" value="check all" onclick="$(this.form).getInputs('checkbox').each(function (elem) {elem.checked = true;});" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

& it works fine for me in Firefox 3.0.8 (as well as IE)...

I disagree with the other answers... this.form should be fine (gets the form object from the submit button, which should then let you get the checkboxes from it via getInputs).

What is the actual issue? Nothing happening at all? If so, the only thing i can think off is, are the checkboxes in the same form as the button?

**EDIT:** If your code is effectively the same as the above & its not working, the best I can suggest is that you turn your onclick into a propper function call & then use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to work out which specific bit isn't working. I.e. make your code look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="prototype-1.6.0.3.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        function checkAll(button) {
            var form = $(button.form);
            var inputs = form.getInputs('checkbox');
            inputs.each(function (elem) {
                elem.checked = true;
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" /> Test 1<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" /> Test 2<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" /> Test 3<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" /> Test 4<br/>
        <input class="submit" type="button" value="check all" onclick="checkAll(this)" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you can put break points in the function & make sure that 'button', 'form' and 'inputs' are what you expect them to be and that the 'elem' in the each loop is too.

Comment: Nothing is happening at all.  I tried it with Safari, and again nothing is happenning.  Only IE seems to work.  The only different between my code and your sample is that I don't have "id=test1" for every checkbox, partly because it's dynamically generated.

Comment: Weird... only good thing is that since the issue is in firefox, at least you have access to firebug to help track the problem down (see my edit above).

Answer (score 0):

The form is the parent of the input, so this.form shouldn't make sense. Use an ID selector or parent.

Second thing - declare this js to assign action on document load, this way is a bit messy, separate js from html to have a clean flexible codebase.

In jQuery it'd be sth like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.('#submitId').click(function(){ 
    // check the checkboxes
    });
}
```

in prototype should be similar.

Comment: All input elements have a this.form attribute that refer to the form they belong to.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the solution in this link:
http://www.ryboe.com/2008/07/10/select-all-checkboxes-with-prototype-js.html

If you don't wanna click, try this:

```
var form = $('options');
checkboxes = form.getInputs('checkbox');
checkboxes.each(function(e){ e.checked = 0 });
```

Answer (score -1):

What is you replace

```
$(this.form)
```

with

```
$('MYFORMNAME')
```

?

Comment: `this` should in this case refer to the submit button, so I'd guess `this.form` is not the right thing to use. My gut feeling is =boj= is right :)

Comment: I disagree... 'this' should be the submit button, so 'this.form' should be the form (assuming the button is inside the form), which should hold all the inputs.